# Upgrade laptop hardware (RAM is more than possible)

Tags: laptop, memory

Aida64 shows the maximum memory on my ultrabook 16 GB

4GB + 4GB on the motherboard.

I want to increase to 16 GB of memory. But the maximum is 16 GB, and 4 is already on the motherboard.
If I put 16, then the total will be 20 (which is more than specified in the processor specification)

How will the laptop behave if I install more memory than possible?
I only have one slot so I want to use the maximum potential memory.

1. Will there be a problem with the operation of such a board with 16 GB? (in the amount of 20 GB)
2. What is the priority of the main memory? Installed separately or built-in?
3. Will the laptop work normally with over-memory? (cuts off excess or does it cause errors?)

My processor: https://ark.intel.com/en/products/85214/Intel-Core-i7-5500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz

Comment: It's not clear if you have 4 or 4+4 GB currently installed. In any case, simply buy 2*8 GB of compatible RAM and replace the existing one entirely. That's the easiest, cheapest and most compatible solution, as one 16 GB module might not work at all anyway.

Comment: Be warned that hardware recommendations are not appropriate here. If you want to know which memory you can buy, ask at [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). But probably 2 sticks of 8gb is the best option (dual-channel is better).

Comment: 1) 2*8 - I only have one slot, 2) Thanks

Comment: @Ievgen - is the existing "_on-board_" memory soldered to the motherboard, and thus impossible to remove? or would you be replacing a single module for a new single module?

Comment: 1 module can be raplaced, and 4gb soldered to the motherboard. Sorry for my english. And maximum is 16 Gb (via CPU maximum in specifications)

Comment: If the maximum amount of memory supported by your system is 16 GB, then the maximum amount of memory you can install using a single module is a 8 GB module.  You can confirm this fact by looking a the manual, or supplying us the information, and somebody will submit an answer.

Comment: Also, jump on to the Kingston site, plug in the system details in the memory configurator and it will tell what your options are.